# ObjectListView not displaying images

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.8, objectlistview

So, I've been trying to make the objectlistview to display cover image next to the title.
[imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9W2k.png)

I want every row to have its own image of the album image, but the ImageAspectName doesnt seem to.. work?
This is my item object, im using:

```
public class AudioDefinition
    {
        // metadata
        public Image audioCover;
        public string audioTitle;
        public string audioArtists;
        [...]
    }
```

the title and all are all there, but no images are displayed

How can i fix this issue?

Comment: Adding a tag for which source file editor you're using isn't helpful (you could be using notepad for all we care). Instead, what UI framework are you using? WinForms, WPF, something else? See [mre].

Comment: im using windows forms new framework 4.8

Comment: Now, can you show code for how `AudioDefinition` objects are bound to the view? I notice that your class contains _fields_ like `public Image audioCover`. Usually, to use a class for binding, you would want _properties_ like `public Image AudioCover {get; set;}` and optionally have those properties issue `PropertyChanged` notifications when modified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the `ImageAspectName` requires a property instead of a field:

```
public Image AudioCover { get; set; }
```

You probably have to set `OwnerDraw` to `true` for the OLV to support image rendering:

```
myOlv.OwnerDraw = true;
```